# Getting a jks file from git-repo using spring cloud config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am using spring cloud config server. 
In one of my apps I get a key-store which stored in resources folder:

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=12345678
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsign
server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
```

I want to get the keystore.jks from the repo which contains all the regular properties such as application.properties etc.
My questions are:
1. Can I store the .jks file on the git repo and getting it to my service?
2. How do I ensure that file will go only to the appropriate service?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm facing same problem here, have you found a solution for this problem? @Yosi Karl

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but I feel the same solution may help others to implement.
I came across the same issue few weeks back and I have implemented the same as below:
In my current implementation, I am using below code to load the jks file:

```
Resource res = resLoader.getResource(filePath);
jksKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
jksKeystore.load(res.getInputStream(), clientHeaderInfo());// clientHeaderInfo() method is used to load custom header information
```

To handle custom path to read from Spring cloud config server, we need to set complete http link to "server.ssl.key-store" property. example: http://localhost:8888/application/profile/sample.jks?useDefaultLabel=useDefaultLabel

coming back to the customization side, we need to add custom protocol resolver to the spring context as below:

```
@Configuration

public class CustomProtocolResolverRegistrar implements ApplicationContextAware {
@Value("${customurl.prefix:chttp:}")
private String urlPrefix;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    if (applicationContext instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext
            = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        configurableApplicationContext.addProtocolResolver((location, resourceLoader)-> {
            if(StringUtils.hasText(location) && location.startsWith(urlPrefix)) {
                  try {
                      return new CloudResource(location.replace(urlPrefix, ""));
                  }
                  catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                      logger.error("Exception while getting CloudResource : {}",e);
                  }
               }
               return null;
        });
    }
} }
```

Later add CustomResource Implementation as below:

```
public class CustomResource extends UrlResource {

private String path;

private URL url;

public CustomResource(URL url) {
    super(url);
    this.url = url;
}

public CustomResource(String path) throws MalformedURLException {
    super(path);
    this.url = new URL(path);
    this.path = path;
}

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    
    URLConnection con = this.url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    
    ResourceUtils.useCachesIfNecessary(con);
    try {
        return con.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        if (con instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
            ((HttpURLConnection) con).disconnect();
        }
        throw e;
    }
}
```

the final step is we need to auto configure the class to be picked up by the spring loader:
Create META-INF/spring.factories file under resource folder and auto configure your class as below:
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
com.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomProtocolResolverRegistrar

**Note:** if you are using git as a backend then the basepath should be configured properly to server the jks file to the client request.
it should fix the above issue.

Please correct me if there is any other better approach.